# django: ImportError: No module named question_answers.models

Tags: python, django

here is my django code

folder structure

```
edutech_quiz-->question_answers-->models.py
```

test.py file

```
from question_answers.models import Quiz, Category, Option, SubcategoryName
import os, sys
import argparse
```

error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from question_answers.models import Quiz, Category, Option,SubcategoryName
ImportError: No module named question_answers.models
```

but it work fine on python shell

```
In [4]: from question_answers.models import Quiz, Category, Option, SubcategoryName

In [5]: Category.objects.all()
Out[5]: []
```

how can I solve the import error

Comment: Can you show your folder structure?

Comment: edutech_quiz-->question_answers-->models.py

Comment: Imports should start from `manage.py` file. So if `edutech_quiz` is at the same level than `manage.py` you sould import `from edutech_quiz.question_answers.models import Quiz, Category, Option, SubcategoryName`

Comment: yeah its on same level. Its work fine on python shell

Comment: Which command are you using to launch your tests ?

Comment: `python manage.py shell`  and then `run test.py`

Comment: Have you tried `python manage.py test` ?

Comment: @ PhilipGarnero  No, I am not tried this one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added 'question_answers' into the INSTALLED_APPS? I know that maybe it's a silly question, but sometimes this is the problem...

Comment: yeah I am added 'question_answers' into the INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Have you tried to run "python manage.py test question_answers" ?